# How to revert git add?

Tags: git, github

I wanted to branch off my master into a new branch, say new-branch. However, I accidentally ran `git checkout -b add new-branch`.

Now I cannot view any of my other branches or checkout to my origin master. The command seems to have created a new repo locally.

I've tried using `git revert` to fix this, to no avail.
I would like to know how to get to my origin repo and delete the submodule.

Comment: The command you stated in your first paragraph will only create a new branch called `add` from an existing ref called `new-branch`. If `new-branch` is an unknown ref, the command should fail ("fatal: 'new-branch' is not a commit and a branch 'add' cannot be created from it").

Comment: That is what I expected but it created a submodule.

Comment: @BeulahAkindele (just a sidenote) You actually wanted to name a branch *add*? If so, this is a really bad idea. There are billions of words or word combinations. Only a few dozens are used for git commands themselves. Don't shoot yourself in the foot by choosing one of them as a branch name.

Comment: @RomainValeri No, I don't mean I want to name a branch "add", but I see where the misunderstanding stems from. I meant I did not expect the command to execute successfully as knittl said in her comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking I should just delete the question but I was just in the wrong directory.

So to get my old branches, I just `cd` into the appropriate directory and to delete the submodule `git rm --cached unintended-branch-name`.

Comment: But thanks for the feedback :-) Useful to finally understand what was going on, but not everyone does it.